# React does not wait for async function before mounting components

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using a mock json-server to hold user information in my React app. I am working on storing settings and preferences for users. I have a setting page implemented through a Route component. I am displaying the settings configurations on this page. I am fetching the user settings in App.tsx :

```js
const fetchUser = async (id:number) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5001/users/${id}`)
    const user = await res.json()
    return user
}

const getSettings = async () => {
    const user = await fetchUser(0)
    setSettings(user.settings); 
}
```

Then I am passing down the state variable for settings through `useContext`.

```js
const [settings, setSettings] = useContext(userContext);
```

This works fine when I start on the root page and then go to the settings. However, if the user goes directly to the settings page, the setting state is initially null and I cannot access its values. I tried to fetch the settings again in the setting page component with `useEffect` but React does not wait for async functions to complete before mounting the components.

```js
const getSettings = async (id:number) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5001/users/${id}`)
    const user = await res.json()
    const settings = user.settings
    setSettings(settings);
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (!settings) getSettings(0); 
}, [])
```

Is there a way to get around this? I would like to access the settings state throughout the app but the user should not have to start with the root component.

Note: It does work if I check that the value is null before use like this :

```js
settings?.test.difficulty
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below change for useEffect:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    if (!settings) await getSettings(0); 
}, [])
```

Comment: This gives the following error : 

Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'